# Executing simple Spark Jobs in Hydrosphere Mist

Tags: scala, rest, apache-spark

I created spark job similar to this: https://github.com/Hydrospheredata/mist/blob/master/examples-spark2/src/main/scala/SimpleContext.scala

changed the import statments to:

```
import io.hydrosphere.mist.lib.spark2.{ContextSupport, MistJob}
```

as existing import `import io.hydrosphere.mist.api.{ContextSupport, MistJob}` cannot resolve.

Created jars using `sbt package` and added it to `router.conf`, which looks like:

```
first-job = {
  path = "path to jar"
  className = "SimpleContext$"
  namespace = "foo"
}
```

The `curl` command to run the above job fails returning

> The requested resource could not be found.

However `curl` commands when pointed to the existing `mist-examples-spark2.jar` runs fine. Does this mean the problem lies while jar creation?. Has anyone able to run Mist Jobs?

The logger in console where i ran `mist-master` showed:

```
17-07-11 21:56:52 [mist-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18] ERROR phere.mist.master.JobEndpoints:44 Job's loading failed for first-job
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/hydrosphere/mist/lib/spark2/MistJob
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
.
.
```

Is there a problem with import statments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, we are working to make our library better and it leads to that it can have binary incompatibility between versions. It means that you should ensure that your local mist installation( or version of docker image) is same as the version of mist-lib that you use to build job.

Comment: I am using `mist-0.12.2-2.1.1`. included `libraryDependencies += io.hydrosphere" %% "mist-lib-spark2" % "0.11.0"` in SBT file.

Comment: Please update `libraryDependencies` section in sbt:
`libraryDependencies += io.hydrosphere" %% "mist-lib-spark2" % "0.12.2"`

Comment: @Vadim Chelyshov can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493750/pass-external-dependency-for-building-spark-submit-hydrosphere-mist