# Pass external dependency for building spark-submit Hydrosphere-mist

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I'm currently using spark with Hydrosphere mist.

My project depends on external libraries(**.jar** files) and some other packages like

```
 1. somejarfile.jar
 2. org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.4,
 3. org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.7.4
```

To pass the external dependency in the mist I can Configure context with run-options.

to configure with the external jar.

```
mycontext.run-options="--jars somejarfile.jar"
```

to configure with external packages.

```
mycontext.run-options="--packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.7.4"
```

Is it possible to configure run-options with both jar and packages, something like below?

```
`mycontext.run-options="--jars somejarfile.jar, --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoopclient:2.7.4"`.
```

I got stuck here. Any help in going with the above problem will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you simply remove the comma?

Comment: @Oli You saved my day. It indeed worked. Can you help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53496235/aws-bad-request400-spark