# aws bad request(400) spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I'm trying to read orc file from s3. I'm able to read it from spark-shell as you can see below.

```
scala> val df = spark.read.format("orc").load("s3a://bucketname/testorc/people/")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, age: int ... 1 more field]
```

and have run spark-shell with below configuration.

```
--master spark://ipaddress \
--packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.0.7-s_2.11,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.7.4,com.typesafe:config:1.2.1 \
--conf "spark.driver.memory=4g" \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint=s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem \
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true \
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true \
--conf spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version=2 \
--conf spark.speculation=false \
--conf "spark.executor.memory=3g" \
```

But when I try to read the same file from s3 using spark with hydrosphere mist. I get the below error:

```
Status Code: 400, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 123456ABDGS, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Bad Request,
```

And below is my spark configuration with mist.

```
mist.context-defaults.spark-conf = {
      spark.master = "spark://ipaddress"
      spark.default.parallelism = 3
      spark.cores.max = 4
      spark.executor.cores = 1
      spark.driver.memory = "1g"
      spark.executor.memory = "1g"
      spark.cassandra.connection.host = "cassandrahost"
      spark.eventLog.enabled = false
      spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled = true
      spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 50
      spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint=s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
      spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
      spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true"
      spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true"
      spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version=2
      spark.speculation=false
    }
```

scala code to read file :

```
val df = spark.read.format("orc").load("s3a://bucketname/testorc/people/")
```

What I'm missing here? please help.

**edited question**

Passing external dependency through context run-options.

```
mist.context.abc.run-options = "--packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.7.4,com.typesafe:config:1.2.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the same `--packages` settings into your context as you mentioned in the first example with `spark-shell`.

Comment: I'm adding packages through run-options. I'have updated the question.

Comment: How you are running mist?Is it on the same node where `spark-shell` example works?

Comment: Yes. Both are on the same node. I think the problem is with Signature version(V4). When I switch s3 region from Asia-Pacific (Mumbai supports only v4) to Asia-Pacific (Singapore it supports both v2 and v4) it worked.